# WCF: HTTP 400 Bad Request on self hosted service

Tags: wcf, servicehost, bad-request

I have this interface:

```
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILocationService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool RegisterForNotification(string name, string uri);

        [OperationContract]
        bool UnRegisterForNotification(string name);
    }
```

and this service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class LocationBasedService : ILocationService
    {
        #region Registrations
        public bool RegisterForNotification(string name, string uri)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool UnRegisterForNotification(string name)
        {
            return true;
        }     
        #endregion
    }
```

and the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="PushNotifications.Server.Service.LocationBasedService" >
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/LocationBasedService"
                 binding="basicHttpBinding"                 
                 contract="Services.Interface.ILocationService"/>
      </service>      
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Self hosted in a WPF application using ServiceHost.  The code for this goes like this:

```
private void startSrv_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try 
            {
                host = new ServiceHost(typeof(LocationBasedService));
                host.Open();
                AddDiagnosticMessage("service successfully initialized");
                AddDiagnosticMessage(string.Format("{0} is up and running with these end points", host.Description.ServiceType));
                foreach (var se in host.Description.Endpoints)
                    AddDiagnosticMessage(se.Address.ToString());
            }
            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {
                AddDiagnosticMessage(string.Format("The service operation timeod out. {0}", ex));
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ex)
            {
                AddDiagnosticMessage(string.Format("Could not start host service. {0}", ex));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AddDiagnosticMessage(ex.Message);
            }                  
        }
```

The service starts without exceptions.  However, when I submit the url http://localhost:8000/LocationBasedService to my browser, I get HTTP 400 Bad Request.  If I try to create a WCF client using Visual Studio's Add Service Reference, I get the following error:

'http://localhost:8000/LocationBasedService'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:8000/LocationBasedService.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

IF I try to invoke the client, using the following code, I get a timeout exception.

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            statusMessages.Add(GetFormattedMessage("initiailing client proxy"));
            var ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/LocationBasedService");
                     var proxy = ChannelFactory<ILocationService>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), ep);          
            var register = proxy.RegisterForNotification("name1", @"http://google.com");
            if (register)
            {  Console.Writeline(register.ToString()); }
        }
```

Could someone please give some insights onto what I missed.  This was supposed to be an easy exercise :!

TIA.

Comment: I made some progress with viewing meta data by adding ServiceMetaData behavior but still cannot get service to respond to simple client request without timeouts.  This is all with default BasicHttpBindings.

Answer (score 2):

The Bad HTTP request was solved by adding this code:

```
 host = new ServiceHost(typeof(LocationBasedService), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/LocationBasedService"));

  // Enable metadata publishing.
   ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
   smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
   smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
   host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    host.Open();
```

As for service timeouts, this was being caused by my personal firewall.  I had to add Visual Studio to the list of allowed applications.

Back in business.

Comment: Spoke too quick. Test WCF client works but through code,I cannot get past timeout.

Comment: If, however, I run my client from another solution (another instance of Visual Studio Express) it works ok.  Before, I had client test code in same WPF app as Service Host code, both using same app.config.